# onDestroy() method doesn't work

Tags: android

first I used onDestroy() method as below to make something when my app is closed.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer2.stop();
}
```

But it causes a runtime error. I used onStop() method instead and problem was solved. But I wonder why onDestroy doesn't work? Can you explain please.

```
@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer2.stop();
}
```

> I was made some changes on my code and now there is no error when I
>   changed onStop() with onDestroy() I can't understand how but it works.

Comment: It would help to tell us what error you're getting.

Comment: Could you post the error you receive from the log?

Comment: When you say "my app is closed", does this mean that you hit the back button until you exit completely from your app, or is this only happening when you just hit the home button?

Comment: @faridmovsumov I don't understand why you would want to stop the music in onDestroy(). When, you look at it from a user's perspective, it seems very odd. Whatever you are doing in onStop() appears appropriate. If you want the music to continually play even when you the user is no longer inside an app, you should be using a Service.

Comment: it is very small app just for joke.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be that your mediaPlayer variable was nulled out(destroyed) before arriving in onDestroy. And the error you were seeing was a nullpointerexception.

You could put your stuff back into the ondestroy method and add a simple null test before doing anything with your mediaPlayer :

```
@Override protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
      mediaPlayer.stop();
      mediaPlayer2.stop();
    } 
 }
```

Comment: İf it will be null how can I stop this music?

Comment: You have to stop it before you null it out before in your code. But first test if you still have an error using this code. AND POST YOUR ERROR !! So we know what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Reframe your code :

```
@Override 
 protected void onDestroy() 
 { 
    mediaPlayer.stop(); 
    mediaPlayer2.stop(); 
    super.onDestroy(); 
 }
```

You were first destroying the object and then retrieving data from it, which can't be possible.
So first, retrieve all data and then call `super.onDestroy();`

This should work out.

Comment: @faridmovsumov, show the error that you are getting. If its nullpointer, then are you sure the mediaplayer's are not null. Also show the onStop code that you have used with this updated onDestroy().

Comment: @faridmovsumov, if you got the solution, click on any answer that helped you the most and "Mark as Answer". That will mark the thread as SOLVED - else others will come trying to help you and waste their times.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try the other way?

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer2.stop();
    super.onDestroy(); //finally
}
```

I does like this my applications. And I guess you should take a look at how these callbacks work.

Comment: Ok. Can you paste the stacktrace?